# How to track number of events per unique user on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have an application that tracks the event where a user marks a 'post' as a favorite. In Google Analytics, I can see how many times the favorite-event has been triggered, and I can find out how many unique users have triggered it. Let's say 2000 favorite-events were triggered, and 1000 unique users triggered them. That would mean an average of 2 favorites per user.

I want to track/see how many favorite-events were actually triggered by the unique users, and group them by the number.
Let's say that 2 of the users have triggered 50 favorite-events each, and the rest has 1 or 2 favorites.

I need a list to see those numbers, for example like this:

```
[2 users]    [favorited] [50 times]
[1000 users] [favorited] [1 time]
```

Is there a way to achieve this without having to use custom variables and/or dimensions?

Comment: You should be able to rely on Analytics own "unique users" when doing reports, if you track the events - but for sake of documentation, I'd recommend including a custom dimension/variable yourself if the metric is important which shouldn't be a big change if you already track events. Then you'll also have it for other possible usages.

Comment: This would be better asked on the webmasters@stackexchange.com site, as it is not about code but about the reporting interface.